# Erroring with acs data in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the acs data and i get a strange error running this commands:

```
library(acs)
api.key.install(key="MY API KEY ")
geo<-geo.make(state=c("NY"),
              county=c(5, 47, 61, 81, 85), tract="*")

race <- acs.fetch(endyear = 2012, span = 1, geography = geo,
                  table.number = "B19001", col.names = "pretty")
```

I get the error :

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I cant understand why

Answer (score 0):

The geom make API is returning a NULL data type in the matrix. R data types do not include NULL but NA. That is why you are getting that problem.